# Send a message to a Facebook profile using an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating an iPhone application using the Facebook SDK. How do I post a message to a selected friend such that the message can be found in their profile?

I have no idea how to implement this.

Comment: Presumably the Facebook SDK / API documentation would include an example of this, as it sounds like a common requirement?  Have you read the docs there well?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook does not allow messages to be sent via the API at this time. Applications can send notifications, but nothing but Facebook has access to the message/inbox API yet.

Comment: By the OPs use of "the message should be found in their profile", I think they're looking to post a public message on a user's wall, rather than send them a direct message.  If that's the case, it's easily done - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/